# running multiple instances of pyglet with multiprocessing library in python

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, pyglet, xserver

I have a python code that visulizes a driving scenario in python. The code uses pyglet. Lets say the code is

`vis_traj(input_A)`

I need to visualize two scenarios at the same time. And I am trying to run them on separate processor using multiprocessing library.

`p1 = Process(target = vis_traj, args=(input_A))
p2 = Process(target = vis_traj, args=(input_B))
p1.start()
p2.start()`

But I get an error and it seems like they can't use X server at the same time:

XIO:  fatal IO error 25 (Inappropriate ioctl for device) on X server ":1"
      after 228 requests (228 known processed) with 0 events remaining.

XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":1"
      after 230 requests (230 known processed) with 18 events remaining.

XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":1"
      after 228 requests (228 known processed) with 0 events remaining.

Is there anyway to circumvent this error?

Answer (score 1):

I happened upon this question while struggling for an answer. I was able to get my code to work by moving all the `pyglet` related classes **and imports** into the function that I run in `Process()`. I suspect that the `pyglet` library has global state that has to be unique for each process.

I was hinted to this by another answer that I can't now find that pointed me in the right direction.